# Replacing lines in a text file with C

Tags: c, printf, scanf, fgets

I have a configuration file that I need to alter.

The structure of the file is:

```
resolution 12x34
interval 1234
```

So two strings with a whitespace delimiter. The code I use to alter it is this:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(configuration_file, "a+");
char str[100], key[100], value[100];
if(fp) {
    while(fgets(str, 100, fp) != NULL) {
        if(2 == sscanf(str, "%s %s", &key, &value)) {
            if(strcmp(key, "resolution") == 0){
                if(msg->resolution){
                    fprintf(fp, "%s %s\r\n", key, msg->resolution);
                }
            } else if(strcmp(key, "interval") == 0) {
                if(msg->interval) {
                    fprintf(fp, "%s %d\r\n", key, msg->interval);
                }
            } else {
                fputs(str, fp);
            } 
        } else {
            fputs(str, fp);
        }
    }
} else {
    (void)printf("-- Configuration file not found (%s)\r\n --", configuration_file);
}
fclose(fp);
```

The idea was to read it line by line. According to the documentation for `fgets` says that it stops at newlines. String-scan each line and parse them into a key and value. So far so good, acting as expected. And then print the new line to the file, overwriting the line it had just scanned. This is where the problem comes in. If I use `fprintf`, only the first value, resolution, is processed. The result of it is:

```
resolution oldxres
resolution newxres
```

It overwrites the wrong line and skips the second entirely.

If I remove the `fprintf` and instead simply print the values it has found, it prints both as it is supposed to.

What am I missing here? Does `fprintf` push the file pointer?

Comment: `a+` is not the same as `rw`. There are more errors.

Comment: Following the `fgets` you have to (of course!) rewind the filepointer to the beginning of the line.

Comment: And, of course too, the new line must be _exactly_ the same length as the old line. So replacing `12x34` with `123x456` can never work as it will overwrite the beginning of the next line

Comment: @PaulOgilvie thanks for the advice. Wasn't aware that you had to rewind the file pointer or that the lines had to be the exact same length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And then print the new line to the file, overwriting the line it had just scanned.

Files don't work this way. Write to a new file. When finished, rename the new file to the old name. Alternatively, read the entire file into memory, change the contents in memory, then write it back.

You can rewrite individual lines is if the modified line never becomes longer than the original one. Otherwise the modified line will spill over the next line you have not read yet, and destroy it. In order to prevent this you would need some kind of look-ahead buffer, which is just too cumbersome and error-prone. In the worst case you'd need to read the entire file anyway.

Comment: Hadn't thought of the length of the modified line and subsequently feel a bit stupid now. Was not a good approach. Thank you for the suggestion. Works like charm!